# VBA Excel - Lopp through Slicer Object and copy and save data

Tags: vba, loops, pivot, slice

I have 3 Slicer filters on a Pivot Table (COUNTRY, CITY, PERSON))and want to loop through all the end results and save the data as a pdf.

So if I select COUNTY and CITY I need to loop from all the PERSONs, save their data to a pdf and then move to the next PERSON.

I've been trying but am now overloaded with infos and have no idea how to get it to work:

```
Sub saveResultsAsPDF ()

Dim mySlicerCache As SlicerCache 
Dim mySlicerCacheLevel As SlicerCacheLevel 
Dim mySlicerItem As SlicerItem

Set mySlicerCache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("PERSON") 
Set mySlicerCacheLevel = mySlicerCache.SlicerCacheLevels(2)

For Each mySlicerItem In mySlicerCacheLevel.SlicerItems    
    saveRangeToPDF
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Slices, but if I understand your general question, you want to manipulate a pivot table, save the results to a PDF, then repeat. How about this:

1. Manipulate the pivot.  Add filters, etc. Refresh the pivot when your ready.
2. Save the entire worksheet as a new PDF file.
3. Continue your loop.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but i'm looking to loop through the slice object items.